# Как прочитать файл с исходником на ideone?

Tags: c++, linux, файлы, ideone

Не могу понять, где относительно исполняемого файла лежит файл с исходным кодом.

Пробовал такие варианты: https://ideone.com/K0Xt0A

```
__FILE__
"./" __FILE__
"../" __FILE__
```

Comment: Есть большое подозрение, что к моменту запуска исходник просто стирают...

Comment: @Harry, а зачем его стирать?

Comment: Может в /tmp лежит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак.

```
system("ls -laR /home");
```

вкупе c `pwd` [дает](https://ideone.com/SlEZBw), что наш каталог пуст - только выполнимый `prog`. Но можно попасть и зацепить в соседнем процесс компиляции - типа

```
/home/mkgHPB:
total 12
drwxrwx--- 2 root  1000 4096 Jan  8 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root 4096 Jan  8 13:59 ..
-rw------- 1 20113 1000    0 Jan  8 13:59 ccgHWOGv.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root  root  602 Jan  8 13:59 prog.cpp
```

Т.е. компилируется во временном каталоге в `/home`, при запуске в нем только `prog` - какие еще сделать выводы, как не то, что после успешной компиляции исходник убивается? Или все компилируются в `/home`, и только наш где-то еще? :)

Кстати, прав писать в текущий каталог они не дают, если надо свои файлы написать-почитать - только в `/tmp`.

Comment: Ясненько.. Странный подход... А не знаешь online-компилятора, в котором исходник не убивается перед запуском?

Comment: Да как-то не требовался, так что не проверял :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, https://repl.it/repls/TriangularProfuseApplets

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Как можно не знать http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/?

Comment: @КириллМалышев, ага, работает!

Comment: @AnT, ну как-то ideone хватало раньше :) Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ideone - ффтопку!!!11

Answer (score 1):

Помогу приблизится к поиску:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    system("ls"); #Исполняй линуксовые команды для поиска файла
    return 0;
}
```

У меня вывод такой:

```
Успешно #stdin #stdout 0s 15232KB
prog
```

prog - это уже готовый исполняемый файл. Думаю надо просто хорошенько по папкам походить.

Comment: Нет там ничего. Проверено :) Похоже, что в `/home` они создают временный каталог, в нем компилируют, убирают все .cpp, .o и запускают. Писать можно в `/tmp`, туда права позволяют...