# Вот кто-нибудь может объяснить мне, как оно работает?

Tags: c, указатели

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;

    fp = fopen(__FILE__,"r");

    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        ch = getc(fp);
        putchar(ch);
    }

  fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Читает исходник и выводит его на консоль. Или тебе построчно надо?

Comment: Обычное чтение из файла и вывод на консоль. Путь до текущего файла можно получить из макроса `__FILE__`. Подбробнее о этих макросах можете найти в темах про "директивы препроцессора в Си/С++".

Comment: Оно **никак** не "работает". С чего бы это вдруг исходный файл будет доступен в момент запуска этого кода? Не говоря уже об использовании неинициализированной переменной `ch` и о сохранении результата `getc()` в переменную типа `char`.

Comment: @AnT в таком случае вам следовало ответить "оно может работать, а может и не работать, в зависимости от ситуации". Вот единственно правильное и верное утверждение. Утверждать полную работоспособность или неработоспособность неправильно, особенно учитвая вопрос "как оно работает". И если уж взялись, то пишите полный и нормальный ответ по `undefined behaviour`.

Comment: @Alex Krass: Утверждать, что такая программа "может работать, а может и не работать" - это примерно как говорить, что сломанные часы два раза в сутки показывают правильное время: это верное, но совершенно бесполезное утверждение.

Comment: @AlexKrass, использование неинициализированной переменной - это всегда плохо. Даже если код с ним пока работает, не факт, что на другом компе будет так же. И не факт, что после обновления компилятора будет так же. И ещё в нём серьёзный баг с `я`. И нигде не объявленное требование на то, чтобы исходник лежал рядом. Комментарии снести в чат можно, но смысла не вижу, тем более, этот вопрос через полгода удалится.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90686/discussion-on-question-by-legioneroff--------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> FILE *fp;
> ```

Объявляем указатель на файл. `FILE` - действительно тип данных (структура), этот указатель может указывать на неё. Именно на неё, а не на какое-то "начало файла". Но пока ему не присвоили значение, там лежит просто мусор.

> ```
> fp = fopen(__FILE__,"r");
> ```

Открываем файл исходника для чтения в тектовом режиме. Вместо `__FILE__` препроцессор подставляет с код строку с именем текущего файла. Соответственно, чтобы программа работала, файл с её исходным кодом должен лежать рядом с ней (точнее в её рабочем каталоге, но в большинстве случаев они будут совпадать).
[Обычно это не так.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/929696/178988)

> ```
> while (ch != EOF)
> ```

Пока считанный символ не будет концом файла. Сразу 3 ошибки, связанные с этой строчкой. Во-первых, изначально переменная `ch` ничем не инициализировалась, чтение неинициализированной переменной - это уже UB. Во-вторых, переменная объявлена с типом char, а весь диапазон типа `char` является корректными символами, которые могут встретиться в самом файле. В данном случае для файла в кодировке win1251 концом файла посчитается буква `я`, если она вдруг там окажется. EOF - специальная константа типа int (обычно -1), обозначающая, что читать уже нечего и файл закончился. Это вообще не указатель, и тем более не указатель на конец файла. Ну а третья ошибка в том, что проверка происходит уже после того, как произойдёт вывод на экран, так что [привет буква `я` в конце файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/932414/178988).

> ```
> ch = getc(fp);
> putchar(ch);
> ```

Собственно считываем очередной символ и выводим. Как я уже сказал, выводим лишнее.

> ```
> fclose(fp);
> ```

И закрываем за собой файл когда всё готово.

> Есть, кстати, даже соревнование, заключающееся в том, чтобы написать минимальную программу, которая выводит саму себя на экран.

Программа, выводящая саму себя называется [квайном](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), но почти всегда там запрещается чтение исходника. И уж тем более чтение исходника из файла, который должен просто так лежать рядом.

Comment: @Qwerty - теперь всё понятно.